# Update child table with different where condition in Jooq

Tags: jooq

I have two tables (A & B) A.Id is a foreign key in table B (and a record in table B may or may not exist).
I want to update Table A based on some condition and irrespective of record exists in Table B.
Also want to update table B if it contains a record of A.Id.
How do we do this multiple table update on different condtions in a single execute in Jooq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most database products, you can't update multiple tables in a single statement, so you'll have to run separate statements in jOOQ. By "single execute", you probably mean you want to have the experience of a single operation in the jOOQ API (irrespective of how many statements are being generated), but that also doesn't exist.

So, you just run multiple statements:

```java
ctx.update(A)
   .set(A.X, someValue)
   .where(someCondition)
   .execute();

ctx.update(B)
   .set(B.Y, someValue)
   .where(someCondition)
   .execute();
```

If, for some reason, the single round trip to the server is important to you, you can use the [procedural language API in jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/) to wrap the above in an anonymous block:

```java
ctx.begin(
    update(A)
    .set(A.X, someValue)
    .where(someCondition),

    update(B)
    .set(B.Y, someValue)
    .where(someCondition)
).execute();
```

Or, you can [batch the statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/), but they will be separate statements.